Firestore rule denying request which supposed to be allowed
I have this TypeScript React code, for fetching a firestore collection (using react-firebase-hooks):
const [membersSnapshot, loading, error] = useCollectionData(
  query(
    collection(db, USERS_COLLECTION).withConverter(UserConverter.prototype),
    where(UserFields.FamilyId, "==", familyId)
  )
);

console.assert(error === undefined, error);

Which without rules, works as expected (assertion not failing).
I have added this rule (I'm adding only the relevant parts):
function getUser() {
  return getUserData(request.auth.uid);
}
    
function getUserData(userId) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(userId)).data;
}

function isSignedIn() {
  return request.auth != null;
} 

function inSameFamily(userId) {
  return getUser().familyId == getUserData(userId).familyId;
}

match /users/{userId} {
  allow read: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == userId || isSignedIn() && inSameFamily(userId); 
}

With this rule, the assertion fails,

Assertion failed: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

and I do not understand what's the problem.
I tried to change the where condition, to:
where(UserFields.Email, "==", userEmail)

and expected it to not fail when I'm trying to get the user itself, but it failed.

There's not enough information in your question to know what the problem is.  Your rule has a lot of requirements that we can't observe on our own: 1) Whether or not a user is actually signed in at the time of the request, 2) the IDs and contents of the users documents being fetched.  Without these details, we have no idea how these rules will evaluate for your query.  Please edit the question to show all relevant data so that we can copy it and reproduce the same behavior on our own.

I will also note that the condition on the email field shouldn't have any effect on these rules since that field is never accessed or checked, from what we can see here so far.  And we can't see the value of UserFields.FamilyId to know what the name of that field actually is.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

@AlexMamo, Doug Stevenson
Sorry for not responding earlier, and thanks for the good will.
I solved my problem, and posted an answer.

The problem was that I was using the get() method instead of just using the obvious option, resource - the document that the user try to read from.
Now, I don't know why it didn't work with get, but... I solved it with using recource.
